# How ignore PATH with `source` completion

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

I can't find any 'detailed enough' documentation about `zstyle`, and I'm surprised that no one faced this problem before:

here is what I get with tab completion:

```
source l<TAB>
l2ping*                  lefty*                   libwmf-fontmap*          locate*                  lpq.cups
```

this is certainly/obviously the executable files of my `$PATH`. However, I would like to use `source` with a **local** file, but I can't understand how to change it.

Basically, the command `file` is completed as I expect, so I'd like to tell `zstyle` to use the same rules.

I *guess* that I could adapt `:completion:*:killall:* 'ps -u $USER -o cmd h'`, to do the job, but this would be quite ugly and I'm looking for a zstyle-builtin option.

I *thought* that I could adapt something like `':completion:*:cd:*'  ignore-parents parent pwd` to `source`, but the completion result never changes ...

---

for information:

```
$ zsh --version
zsh 4.3.17 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
$ zstyle
cache-path
        :completion::complete:* /home/kevin/.oh-my-zsh/cache/
command
        :completion:*:*:*:*:processes 'ps -u kevin -o pid,user,comm -w -w'
        :completion:*:killall:* 'ps -u $USER -o cmd h'
hosts
        :completion:*:hosts 192.168.0.101 git.bri.st.com crx672 bastion.inrialpes.fr 192.168.0.5 idrouille 129.88.69.73 idrouille.imag.fr koguis 192.168.1.4 127.0.0.1 koguis.imag.fr localhost crx672.cro.st.com 192.168.1.100 github.com 192.168.1.101 sourceware.org gnx2034.gnb.st.com gnx2528.gnb.st.com ctf.stri.pe 10.0.0.2 127.0.0.1 kevin localhost.localdomain localhost ::1 kevin localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6 kevin localhost
ignored-patterns
        :completion:*:*:*:users adm amanda apache avahi beaglidx bin cacti canna clamav daemon dbus distcache dovecot fax ftp games gdm gkrellmd gopher hacluster haldaemon halt hsqldb ident junkbust ldap lp mail mailman mailnull mldonkey mysql nagios named netdump news nfsnobody nobody nscd ntp nut nx openvpn operator pcap postfix postgres privoxy pulse pvm quagga radvd rpc rpcuser rpm shutdown squid sshd sync uucp vcsa xfs
        :completion:*:functions '_*'
list-colors
        :completion:*:*:kill:*:processes '=(#b) #([0-9]#) ([0-9a-z-]#)*=01;34=0=01'
        :completion:* ''
menu
        :completion:*:*:*:*:* select
single-ignored
        * show
tag-order
        :completion:*:cd:* local-directories directory-stack path-directories
url-globbers
(eval)  :url-quote-magic 'zmodload -i zsh/parameter;
     reply=( noglob
         ${(k)galiases[(R)(* |)(noglob|urlglobber|globurl) *]:-}
         ${(k)aliases[(R)(* |)(noglob|urlglobber|globurl) *]:-} )'
url-local-schema
        :urlglobber ftp file
url-metas
        :url-quote-magic:* '*?[]^(|)~#{}='
url-other-schema
        :urlglobber http https ftp
url-seps
(eval)  :url-quote-magic:* 'reply=(";&<>${histchars[1]}")'
use-cache
        :completion::complete:* 1
user-commands
        :completion:*:*:git:* 'flow:description for foo'
```

Comment: The standard, [POSIX-compliant](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#dot) behavior of `.`, for which `source` is a synonym in shells that have it, specifies that `$PATH` shall be searched for files that do not contain slash.  If you want to restrict the search and completion to local files, a simple way is to type `./` first.  This is probably cleaner than messing up the shell completion.

Comment: it makes sense ... but I'm used to my bash habits, and I'd like to get the same behavior with zsh :)

Comment: I haven't had enough coffee yet. So you would like the zsh shell builtin `source` to complete the same way as when you auto-complete a binary?

Comment: yes, indeed (I thought it was specific to `file`, but it's actually the *default* behavior for binaries)

Comment: I've done **a lot** of reading on this and I'm confused. @jw013 is right that `.` will search `$PATH` first if the file does not contain a slash, but according to the zsh manual, `source` is the same as `.` except that the current directory is always searched and is always searched first, before directories in `$PATH`. So my understanding is `source l<TAB>` should match the local file in the directory first. However, it's not behaving that way for me either. Perhaps an advanced zsh user such as @Gilles has some insight.

Comment: Okay, I disabled all autocomplete in ~/.zshrc to just get the most basic completion. Now `source l<TAB>` works as expected and matches the file in my working directory. As soon as I `compinit`, the behavior reverts. So it's definitely a setting that can be modified.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of zsh 4.3.10, `source` is completed by `_source` which doesn't look up any zstyle. It might be possible to set a style used by `_files`, but that would be hackish, even by zsh standards.

I suggest that you rewrite the `_source` function to your liking, it's not very long. Something like:

```
_my_source () {
  if [[ CURRENT -ge 3 ]]; then
    compset -n 2
    _normal
  elif [[ $service = . ]]; then
      _files -W path
  else
    _files
  fi
}
compdef _my_source source
```

Comment: thanks, it's more complicated than expected, but working perfectly!

Comment: @Gilles Well done!